# How do you prove that (X-Y) ∪ (X-Z) ⊆ (X-(Y∩Z)) is true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Where for sets X, Y, and Z and also their powersets.

This is what I attempted to do:

$(X-Y) ∪ (X-Z)$

$(a∈X∧a∉Y) ∨ (a∈X∧a∉Z)$

$(a∈X)∧ (a∉Y ∨ a∉Z)$

$X ∩ (Y ∪ Z)$

$X - (Y ∪ Z)$

X - (Y U Z) is not the same as X - (Y ∩ Z) so I thought the answer was false. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.  They'll look better, and you'll get more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: @saulspatz Ok I tried to do that

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, and thanks for using MathJax now. 
Note that $a\not\in Y \lor a\not\in Z$ means $\lnot(a\in Y \land a\in Z),$ where $\lnot\;$    means not

Answer (score 2):

$$a\in(X-Y)\cup(X-Z)\implies$$

$$a\in(X-Y)\lor a\in (X-Z)\implies$$

$$(a\in X\land a\not\in Y)\lor (a\in X\land a\not \in Z)\implies$$

$$a\in X\land (a\not\in Y\lor a\not\in Z) \implies$$

$$a\in X\land \lnot(a\in Y \ \land a\in Z)\implies$$

$$a\in X \land \lnot (a\in Y\cap Z)\implies$$

$$a\in X \land a \not\in Y\cap Z\implies$$

$$a \in X - (Y\cap Z)$$

so $$(X-Y)\cup(X-Z)\subseteq X-(Y\cap Z).$$

Comment: Cf. [De Morgan’s Laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)